# Solving a Piecewise ODE

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I am attempting to solve a piecewise ODE.

$y' =  \begin{cases} -1 & \text{for $y \geq 0$}\\ 1 & \text{for $y < 0$} \end{cases}, \qquad y(0)=0, \qquad x \in [0,1]$

I have attempted solving by the

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Piecewise[{{-1, y >= 0}, {1, y < 0}}], y[x], x]
```

However, the error always reports the function y has no arguments. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `DSolve[y'[x] == Piecewise[{{-1, y[x] >= 0}, {1, y[x] < 0}}], y[x], x]`  as error says, `y` needs to have argument.

Comment: I can't seem to get a solution unless I drop the equal sign in the $y\geq 0$ part.